# How to pull data from last Thursday 7:00PM backward

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to pull data from a table using a datetime column.

However, I only need to pull data starting from the most recent Thursday at 7:00PM, and backward an X amount of weeks.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

My current where clause is such:

```
where 
datetime_column <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -4)
and datetime_column >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -4) - 14
```

However this pulls from the start of the day.

Comment: and what you have tried so far? better to include that in question, so we all can see if something is wrong with SQL, and how to correct it.

Comment: Edited the post ^

Answer (score 1):

You can get 7 p.m. last Thursday using:

```
 (values(dateadd(hour, 19,
                 dateadd(day,
                         (case datename(weekday, getdate())
                             when 'Monday' then -4
                             when 'Tuesday' then -5
                             when 'Wednesday' then -6
                             when 'Thursday' then -7
                             when 'Friday' then -1
                             when 'Saturday' then -2
                             when 'Sunday' then -3
                          end),
                         convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))
                        )
                )
) as last_thursday
```

Once you have defined this, you can just use it in a `where` clause.

Note:  This assumes that you are using English-language settings for day-of-the-week.  SQL Server makes it hard to unambiguously get the day of the week, regardless of settings.

Comment: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Comment: @HABO . . . To be honest, I prefer remembering that 2001-01-01 is. Monday and then doing arithmetic off of that.  My point is basically that SQL Server does not make this easy.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff has a version where you can define the weekday, however it gave me the idea to just DATEADD 19 hours to mine which suits my purposes:

```
where datetime_column <= dateadd(hour,19, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -4))
and datetime_column >= dateadd(hour,19, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -4)) - 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Declare @numWeeks int = 14;
 Select FromDate = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 5, getdate()) - (7 * @numWeeks), 0)
      , ToDate = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 5, getdate()), 0) + '19:00';
```

I would calculate the values - then use them:

```
Declare @numWeeks int = 14;

Declare @fromDate datetime = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 5, getdate()) - (7 * @numWeeks), 0)
      , @toDate datetime = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 5, getdate()), 0) + '19:00';

  Where datetime_column >= @fromDate
    And datetime_column <  @toDate
```

This includes all times up to - but not including 19:00.  Adjust as needed for your datetime range.